# Laravel - Bitbucket Pipelines Configuration

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to setup Pipelines with Bitbucket.

I am currently getting a passing build with the following.

```
image: php:7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - cp .env.example .env
          - php artisan key:generate
          - php artisan traqza:clear-everything
          - echo "Done!"
        services:
          - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pipeline'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'username'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

However if I try to add `php artisan migrate` & `php artisan db:seed` to the `script:` section of the pipeline file, I get the following error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver`

I cant figure it out. Any ideas on what would cause this?

Is this a `.env.example` issue with the database username/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by brute force. For the next guy to save them time.

To setup Bitbuckets Pipelines for Laravel ^8.* with a basic build test to validate you have a database connection, and your database seeds. It will also check your phpunit tests.

```
image: php:7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - cp .env.example .env
          - php artisan key:generate
          - php artisan migrate
          - php artisan db:seed
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
          - echo "Done!"
        services:
          - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pipeline'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'username'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

make sure you change your database username, password, and the database name per your .env.example file.

Cheers

Comment: One thing to add, I had to set the following in my .env for it to work `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`. Other than that, this helped me, thanks!